# Mongodb performance issue when sorting

Tags: mongodb, sorting, database-performance

I'm trying to switch mysql to mongodb. But i have an issue about sorting performance.

I have millions of documents as following;

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5af7cbda7500fc509c3098ce"),
    "name": "Task Name",
    "category": "performance",
    "subIssues": [
        {
            "taskId": 10,
            "description": "Task description",
            "createdAt": "2018-05-11 14:37:07.000Z"
        },
        {
            "taskId": 11,
            "description": "Task description",
            "createdAt": "2018-05-11 14:37:07.000Z"
        },
        {
            "taskId": 12,
            "description": "Task description",
            "createdAt": "2018-05-11 14:37:07.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to sorting by "subIssues.taskId", the query is ".tasks.find({"name": "performance"}).limit(10).sort({"subIssues.taskId": -1})". But this query works too slow. I tried another field (sorting by "name"), that worked very fast but sub array wasn't.
Collection indexes;

```
[
    {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    {
        "name" : 1.0
    },
    {
        "subIssues.taskId" : 1.0
    }
]
```

Explain Output;

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "testing.tasks",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "name" : {
                "$eq" : "performance"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "subIssues.taskId" : -1.0
            },
            "limitAmount" : 10,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "name" : 1.0
                        },
                        "indexName" : "name_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "name" : []
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "name" : [ 
                                "[\"performance\", \"performance\"]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ 
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "subIssues.taskId" : -1.0
                },
                "limitAmount" : 10,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "name" : {
                                "$eq" : "performance"
                            }
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "subIssues.taskId" : 1.0
                            },
                            "indexName" : "subIssues.taskId_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : true,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "subIssues.taskId" : [ 
                                    "subIssues"
                                ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "backward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "subIssues.taskId" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "5113848ca8f8",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.4"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

I use mongo 3.6 on centos 7, 16 core, 32gb ram.

what are your suggestions?

Comment: If you have "millions of documents" then what possible usage is a query with no criteria which simply returns everything? Sorted or not there's no real practical use for returning the whole collection to any client program, and especially for "millions of documents". Either you're being a little too "dramatic" in your question style or you're not really conveying what you are doing, or even possibly just don't understand what is so very wrong about returning everything in the database without criteria. You could possibly explain to justify the position at least.

Comment: Of course, i have filter. I just simplified it while write this post. 
I edited post. Sorry my fault.

Comment: Well it will basically come down to "indexes", which is again part of the reason you need to actually state what query conditions as that applies to which index to select just as much as a sort does. More information is better than "simplifiying". Output from the `"explain"` option at least gives an indication of what indexes ( if any ) are in use for the query. Also I'm not really sure what you are expecting from a sort on a property within an array, since all that really happens is the largest or smallest value within the array determines the "document" sort order, depending on direction.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. if i want to sort by name, the query returns in 2 seconds. But if i want to sort by subfield, it returns in 60 seconds. Also if i don't use "limit" operation, mongodb returns "Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit" but the collection already has that index.

"Explain" output has been added to question.

Comment: Looks like you need a compound index. I'n still not sold that the sort is really doing what you expect, but the index should be on both fields here as in `createIndex({ "name": 1, "subIssues.taskId": 1 })`. Though there are some cases where MongoDB can pick up "separate indexes", this is not one of them. So you need a compound index for this case. Still sounds like you're returning way to many documents though, so either you're still not being realistic or the application is still doing something really wrong. `explain(true)` should include the execution stats, which tell a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Try indexing the field you want to sort:
db.records.createIndex( { subIssues.taskId: 1 } )

But i don't think this will work, change your data structure :)

Comment: Already exist index :)
`
 {
  "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
  "numIndexesBefore" : 3,
  "numIndexesAfter" : 3,
  "note" : "all indexes already exist",
  "ok" : 1.0
 }
`